# Centering Div in IE9 without fixed Height/Width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-store-apps, internet-explorer-9

Can I borrow someone's eyes before I drop kick this damn thing out the window?

**SHORT VERSION**: What's the right way to x,y center a div reliably in IE9 when it can not be fixed height/width?

Scenario: I'm customizing the templates of ping federate server that we pass through a windows store app for auth. I mention this because windows store apps (Not to be confused with UWP) uses a jank version of IE9.

My problem...**which I can't even go make a damn codepen for since they don't support IE9 anyway**....is I'm just trying to center the first child `div` both vertically and horizontally.

Now then, IE9 doesn't support flexbox, so no love there. I am however able to do;

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

which does indeed center it nicely, looks great on everything EXCEPT IE as it displays a large white space at the bottom of the screen. Which in turn, also causes scrollbars to appear which aren't even necessary...

Since the `div` can not be of a fixed width/height I have not gotten other fixes to work. It also doesn't help I've been doing .NET stuff so long my css is rusty.

So can someone start my weekend off right and enlighten me to some IE Kung Fu fix so I may praise your name and toast beer to you this evening? :)

Hopefully the snippet below (ran in IE as IE9) will help visualize my issue with this stupid whitespace at the bottom that has become my nemesis...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/1350/blur-blurred-background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
}

div {
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith on the question. :)

Comment: Can we solve using Jquery or javascript?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Technically I could, but I was trying to avoid that route since PingFederate likes to go dink with their templates like they just did their latest release of v8.1.2, so rather than having to go deal with a couple dozen separate html/velocity templates I was really trying to keep it to CSS only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the old way was with an extra element, but a pseudo will do for IE9 :

```css
html, body, body:before {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -0.25em;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 99.5%; /* or white-space on body for security to avoid div wrap under pseudo, 
  do not forget to reset to normal if you choose so */
  min-height: 250px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block; /* i'll be against top or left without disappearing if window is too small */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* text-align: left; */
  }

/* not IE 9 , bg-cover ? */
body {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/1350/blur-blurred-background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: OMFG! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. If you ever find your way to KC there will be all the BBQ and Beer you can consume in a sitting waiting! THANKS A TON!

Comment: @ChrisW. arf, you're teasing me, too far to come and enjoy , i love these times of life

Comment: No worries, I'm in EU often, maybe then. I just wish I understood how the hell that trick worked! lol

Comment: @ChrisW. inline-block element stand on te baseline alike text. their height will set the line-height. If an image is 200px tall, then the line where it stands will be at least 200px. use vertical-align to set it on top, middle or bottom or else value :), here the line-height comes 100% of viewport or more if your div is taller (give a border to the pseudo to see how it works resizing window's height).